# Regex matching 2 similar phrases

Tags: regex, regex-negation

I am trying to match to automatically grade a student's answer to a question where the correct answer is:

```
read and execute for owner and read for everyone
```

The order of their answer doesn't matter so

```
read for everyone and read and execute for owner
```

is an acceptable answer. Then all the fluff (and, for) doesn't matter so I am really just looking for either of these

```
read execute owner read everyone
read everyone read execute owner
```

I can get a regex to accept either answer

```
(?=.*read.*execute.*owner)(?=.*read.*everyone)
```

But obviously that accepts more answer that are clearly wrong like "read execute owner read execute everyone". So I tried using the negative look-ahead for "execute" with everyone, but then it still matches the "execute" for owner and says no regex match.

Is there are way to accomplish what I am trying to do? Thanks.

Comment: It will need a mammoth regex which cannot even be tweeted :)

Comment: That is what I was afraid of. Was really hoping there was something easy. Still going to pray for someone to find one, but I will get the construction hat out and start building.

Comment: You can try with negative lookaheads !!!!!!!!

Comment: If I try to negative lookahead "execute", it find the correct "execute" still and marks it wrong.

Comment: Something like `execute((?!everyone).)*owner` you will have to add many of these

Answer (score 1):

Just make the and/for optional.

```
 # (?=.*(\bread(?:\s+and)?\s+execute(?:\s+for)?\s+owner\b))(?=.*(\bread(?:\s+for)?\s+everyone\b))

 (?=
      .* 
      (                             # (1 start)
           \b read               
           (?: \s+ and )?
           \s+ execute 
           (?: \s+ for )?
           \s+ 
           owner \b 
      )                             # (1 end)
 )
 (?=
      .*           
      (                             # (2 start)
           \b read                
           (?: \s+ for )?
           \s+ everyone \b 
      )                             # (2 end)
 )
```

*Edit*: You could also allow for optionally *any* words between the
key words by excluding all the keywords from between the keywords.
Like this -

```
 #  (?=.*(\bread(?:\s+(?:(?!\b(?:read|execute|owner|everyone)\b).)+?)?\s+execute(?:\s+(?:(?!\b(?:read|execute|owner|everyone)\b).)+?)?\s+owner\b))(?=.*(\bread(?:\s+(?:(?!\b(?:read|everyone|execute|owner)\b).)+?)?\s+everyone\b))

 (?=
      .* 
      (                     # (1 start)
           \b read
           (?:
                # Optional words Between Keywords -
                # not any of this or the other ones keywords
                \s+ 
                (?:
                     (?!
                          \b 
                          (?:
                               read                  # this
                            |  execute               # this
                            |  owner                 # this
                            |  everyone              # other
                          )
                          \b 
                     )
                     . 
                )+?
           )?
           \s+ execute
           (?:
                # Optional words Between Keywords
                \s+ 
                (?:
                     (?!
                          \b 
                          (?:
                               read
                            |  execute
                            |  owner
                            |  everyone
                          )
                          \b 
                     )
                     . 
                )+?
           )?
           \s+ 
           owner \b 
      )                     # (1 end)
 )
 (?=
      .* 
      (                     # (2 start)
           \b read
           (?:
                # Optional words Between Keywords -
                # not any of this or the other ones keywords
                \s+ 
                (?:
                     (?!
                          \b 
                          (?:
                               read                  # this
                            |  everyone              # this
                            |  execute               # other
                            |  owner                 # other
                          )
                          \b 
                     )
                     . 
                )+?
           )?
           \s+ everyone \b 
      )                     # (2 end)
 )
```

Comment: Same comment I made on Kasra's answer. I was hoping to allow them to enter other words besides just and/for and still mark them right as long as they have the right match for everyone/owner, but that maybe asking too much and I might have to go with something like this.

Comment: @jhnewkirk -  If you want to have other stuff between keywords, just keep what you've got. Or, if you have some list of words allowed / disallowed, just put that in where the options are.

Comment: @jhnewkirk  - Added an update that shows a method to include any words between the keywords _except the keywords themselves_. Good Luck!